# WideImage not working on my server

Tags: php, ubuntu

It works on Xampp localhost , but when I try it on my server, it doesnt.

```
require_once "lib/WideImage.php";

$img = WideImage::load('i/big.jpg');
$res = $img ->resize(400, 300);
$res->saveToFile("i/small.jpg");
```

**Server version**: 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1

**Gd** is installed on the server.

Comment: No, it doesn't load the page, how can i turn on the error msg?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` add this at the beginning of your script.

Comment: still not showing me an error msg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little research I found this:

> WideImage is an object-oriented library for image manipulation. It requires **PHP 5.2+** with GD2 extension.

But php version on your server is <5.2 Updating it will help you.

Maybe the problem is in permissions (you don't have permission to create new file).

Comment: tnks, when i run 'phpversion();' it prints "version: 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10"

Comment: @bekman as it's told in you question GD is installed and now I know that php version is above 5.2, Maybe you don't have file creating permission.

Comment: i tried to change permission with 'chmod 777' now i cant even get in to my server. it keeps showing me "No supported authentication methods available"

Comment: Thanks, it was a permission problem, sudo chmod 777 /var/www/i -R fix my problem.

Comment: @bekman I've updated my answer. Now everyone can see the correct solution. Thanks for commenting. You can accept this answer. :)